# How to make a landing page in flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile-development

I have this design i am trying to recreate, i want to make a landing page such that when the user swipes it will move on to the next image, replacing the current one, using listView or scrollable Widget i do not get the desired effect, any ideas on how i can acheive this, any link to a resource i could read up on would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use PageView:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //you can also use pagecontroller to jump to previous/next page
    final PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    return PageView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: controller,
      children: const <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('First Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Second Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Third Page'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```